# Catching the child error in the parent

Tags: c, exec, fork

I am trying to write the following C assignment: a program my-if taking two arguments, that will run the first argument, then run the second argument on success.
Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char ** split(char * s) {
  char ** words = malloc(sizeof(char *));
  int i = 0;
  char * word = strtok(strdup(s), " ");
  while (word) {
    words = realloc(words, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
    words[i] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(words[i++], word);
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  words[i] = NULL;
  return words;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char ** argv1 = split(argv[1]);
  char ** argv2 = split(argv[2]);

  int t = fork();
  if (t == -1)
    exit(1);
  else if (t == 0) 
    execvp(argv1[0], argv1);
  else {
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
      printf("exit status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My problem is to figure how to catch an error in the child process. 
WIFEXITSTATUS is always 0, even if running the same command in the shell then doing 'echo $?' will print 127.
for example my-if 'toto' 'tutu' will give me a WEXITSTATUS = 0, even though

```
$ toto
$ echo $?
$ 127
```

I tried WSIGNALED, WSTOPPED, but I really don't figure how to catch an error. Am I searching in the right direction, or is it something entirely different, for example launching a shell that then executes my command, and the error is inherent to the shell, not to the command?

Comment: Check your return values.  Is `execvp` successful, or is it returning?

Comment: And turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: I use gcc -Wall . Can I do more?

Comment: And the puzzling thing is that whether I try something like "my-if ls ls" or "my-if toto toto", execvp never returns.

Comment: If you include <unistd.h>, you should get a warning with -Wall.  "Puzzling" is different than invoking unspecified behavior.  `argv [1]` is the wrong type for the second argument.

Comment: My mistake, the program is actually a little more complex, and I wished to simplify it for the question, yet the execvp call is correct. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Moreover exec will return (or not) in its own fork. I wish to capture the error in the other fork.

Comment: I updated my answer, check if this information helps you.

Comment: You really should rename `WIFEXITSTATUS`. I can't read it like wIFexitStatus instead of WIFExitSTATUS...

Comment: @fvdalcin, ??? You can't simply reanme it, because those are the offical names. http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much everyone for your input. I simply needed to return the potential return of execv() which then becomes the WEXITSTATUS of the original fork()'s wait().

```
else if (t == 0) 
**return** execvp(argv1[0], argv1);
```

Comment: This will only return if your execvp couldn't be started. Is this what you meant? To return an error, if the command fails?

Comment: As I clearly stated to not get undue help, this is an assignment, which means I am a beginner. So I don't pretend to understand, but now the programs works - for example: my-if "toto" "echo success" and my-if "ls fakestring" "echo success" don't echo success, while: my-if "ls -l" "echo success" does.

Comment: No, your program does not work.  execvp only returns if there is an error.  You are not calling the external program at all.

Comment: I apologize for my rudeness, but yes it works. The three examples in the comment do exactly what they should. Except the second part of it which I forgot to correct in the original post: if(WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0) execvp(argv2[0], argv2);

Comment: `return execvp(...)` is wrong, unless your intent is to fail to notice when you do not successfully exec the external program.  It is coincidental that you are returning an error in that case, but an error message should be emitted.  You are an acknowledged beginner, so try listening to those of us who are not.  If you submit an assignment with `return execvp(...)`, it indicates that you do not understand how `execvp` works.  It is not returning the exit status of the external program.

Comment: Working with the following test program as a first argument to my-if:#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
 printf("Testing");
 exit(0);
} and changing the number inside exit(), I still have the correct behaviour: my-if "testprogram" "echo success" echoes success when exit contains a 0, and doesn't if not. The program is lauched, echoes "Testing", then my-if acts on its exit code accordingly. I don't need the exit code, just to know if there was any error in execvp itself, or in the program it launches.

Answer (score 0):

Change your call to `execvp`.  Try:

```
execvp( argv[1], argv + 1 );
```

Comment: My mistake, the program is actually a little more complex, and I wished to simplify it for the question, yet the execvp call is correct. I will update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if `wait` really returned something. If the return value is not your childpid, then you can not interpret the status.

```
    if(wait(&status) != child)
    {
        printf("Error in wait\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

I use this code to interpret the various states. I think the code is easily enough to understand with the logging comments that I use.

If your child crashed, it will have termainted with a SINGAL instead of exit, and in this case you must check the appropriate macro as well.

```
    if(WIFEXITED(status) == 0 && WIFSIGNALED(status) == 0)
    {
        LOGGER(MODULE_TAG, DEBUG2) << "Child: " << pid << " still running";
        setRunning(true);
        setTerminated(false);
        setTerminationSignal(0);
        setExitStatus(-1);
    }
    else if(WIFSTOPPED(status))
    {
        LOGGER(MODULE_TAG, DEBUG2) << "Child: " << pid << " stopped";
        setRunning(false);
    }
    else if(WIFCONTINUED(status))
    {
        LOGGER(MODULE_TAG, DEBUG2) << "Child: " << pid << " continued";
        setRunning(true);
    }
    else
    {
        setRunning(false);
        setTerminated(true);
        if(WIFEXITED(status))
        {
            LOGGER(MODULE_TAG, DEBUG2) << "Child: " << pid << " terminated normally";
            setTerminationSignal(0);
            setExitStatus(WEXITSTATUS(status));   // Exitcode from the child
        }
        else
        {
            LOGGER(MODULE_TAG, DEBUG2) << "Child: " << pid << " terminated by signal";
            setTerminationSignal(WTERMSIG(status));
            setExitStatus(-1);
        }
    }
```